# Placing window after TaskManager window fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-8.1, z-order, window-position

I'm trying to place a window after TaskManager window and it fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`:

```
if (SetWindowPos(myWindowHndl, taskManagerHndl, left, top, right - left, bottom - top, SWP_NOACTIVATE | flags))
{
    LOG_ERROR("SetWindowPos() succeedded");
}
else
{
    LOG_HIGH("SetWindowPos() failed: " << GetLastError());
}
```

Is there something special with the TaskManager window and is it possible to overcome this? Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of taskManagerHndl? How did you get the handle? Please Show the code for getting the handle.

Comment: @WernerHenze the code is simplified. It maybe another window as well but with other windows I've no problems. In case of task manager `SetWindowPos` fails. I'm sure the handle is of task manager window because I've printed it and checked with Windows Detective to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly the task manager, this is a feature introduced with Vista known as `UIPI`  (user interface privilege isolation). [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx) for more information.

Try running your application elevated. See if it works then. If it does then this is your problem.

Comment: I've Changed the integrity level of my process to 'High' with `icacls` and it solved the problem.